# Equivalent of Oracle if-else trigger on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, triggers

I want to create a sales table. When there is an update on the sales table, the data in the stock table should automatically be decreased.

This is my code in Oracle:

```
create trigger trigger_updatestok11
after insert
on transaksijualbeli for each row
begin
  if (:new.kategoritransaksi in ('beli'))
  then
    update stokbarang set jumlahstok= jumlahstok +:new.jumlah
    where Nobrg=:new.nobrg;
  end if;
  if (:new.kategoritransaksi in ('jual'))
  then
    update stokbarang set jumlahstok= jumlahstok -:new.jumlah
    where Nobrg=:new.nobrg;
  end if;
end;
```

How can I do that in SQL Server?

Comment: Have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Will same `nobrg` appear more than once in the `transaksijualbeli`  ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, SQL Server triggers don't have a `for each row` option - the trigger is fired **once per statement**, and if that `INSERT` statement inserted more than one row, `Inserted` will contain more than one row. You need to write your trigger in a proper, **set-based** fashion, taking into account that `Inserted` can (and *will!*) contain multiple rows - something like this:

```
create trigger trigger_updatestok11
after insert
on transaksijualbeli 
as
begin
    update stokbarang 
    set jumlahstok = jumlahstok + i.jumlah
    from Inserted i
    where stokbarang.Nobrg = i.nobrg
      and i.kategoritransaksi in ('beli');

    update stokbarang 
    set jumlahstok= jumlahstok - i.jumlah
    from Inserted i
    where stokbarang.Nobrg = i.nobrg
      and i.kategoritransaksi in ('jual');

end
```

Comment: isn't the trigger should handles multiple rows of `transaksijualbeli` having the same `nobrg` ?